# xsl for-each node not containing a sub-element

Tags: xslt

The following instruction works for me to select the nodes having either of two subnodes:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/whatever/target[sub1 or sub2]">
```

However, the oposite does not seems to work for me:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/whatever/target[not (sub1 or sub2)]">
```

I want to get a list of target nodes that do not have any of the two subnodes. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post your input xml

Comment: @Guasqueño Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:for-each select="/whatever/target[not (sub1)][not(sub2)]">
```

Comment: Why would anyone every down-vote a correct answer? You get some crazy nutters on SO!

Comment: Well, your answer does not address the question. You did not explain what's wrong with using `/whatever/target[not (sub1 or sub2)]` (there is nothing wrong with it) or why replacing it with `/whatever/target[not (sub1)][not(sub2)]` would make any difference (it wouldn't).

Comment: The nub of his question was "how to select list of target nodes that do not have any of the two subnodes", and my answer was a correct answer to it. I could have been more verbose, but that is still not worth down-voting a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

I found what the error was. The select was very correct and would have produced a result if I had been in the right context. I was in the wrong context within the XML file. My final statement is this:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="parent-or-self::whatever/target[not (sub1 or sub2)]">
```

It could've also been:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="target[not (sub1 or sub2)]">
```

removing the "whatever" from that select as I already was in the "whatever" node.

Sorry, I did not realized I was misleading you by including an absolute path, I was actually using a relative path.

Comment: `parent-or-self` is not a valid XPath axis!

Comment: If you are in the context of the parent node of `target`, then you **should** be using `select="target[not (sub1 or sub2)]"` - not the other expression, which you call your "final statement" and which cannot possibly work.